# How to mask a list using boolean values from another list

Tags: python, list

I have a list like this:

```
x = [True, False, True, False]
```

and a list like this:

```
y = [a, b, c, d]
```

I would like to mask `x` over `y` to get this output:

```
output = [a, c]
```

I know how to do this using `while`/`for` loops, but I'm ideally looking for an elegant one-line of code using list comprehension.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use `zip` and a list comprehension to perform a filter operation on `y` based on corresponding truth values in `x`:

```
x = [True, False, True, False]
y = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

print([b for a, b in zip(x, y) if a])
```

Output:

```
['a', 'c']
```

[`itertools.compress`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress) also does this:

```
>>> from itertools import compress
>>> x = [True, False, True, False]
>>> y = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
>>> list(compress(y, x))
['a', 'c']
```

Answer (score 9):

I think the easiest way is to use `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np
>>> x = [True, False, True, False]
>>> y = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>> np.array(y)[x]
array(['a', 'c'], dtype='<U1')
```

Without `numpy`, You could also enumerate in a list comprehension:

```
>>> [i for idx, i in enumerate(y) if x[idx]]
['a', 'c']
```

Comment: I think the list comprehension option does what the OP asks for: an elegant one line solution

Comment: @sacul. Why do you replace **[a, b, c, d]** by **['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']**. **a, b, c**, and **d** could perfectly represent some kind of object, not necessarily a string

Comment: @eapetcho, just so I can display results in my answer, but you're right, those could be an object of some sort.

Answer (score 4):

There are several ways to do this.

The simplest way would be to zip the two lists together and use a list comprehension to keep the items you want.

```
x = [True, False, True, False]
y = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

print([item for keep, item in zip(x, y) if keep])
```

You can also convert the y array to a numpy array and use the x array to mask the numpy array.

```
import numpy as np

x = [True, False, True, False]
y = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

print(list(np.array(y)[x]))
```

Finally, you can create an empty list, iterate through the x and y arrays using their indexes, and append elements in y to the empty list if the corresponding element in x is True.

```
x = [True, False, True, False]
y = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

temp = []

for index in range(len(y)):
    if x[index]:
        temp.append(y[index])

print(temp)
```

Answer (score 1):

If already have you some function that returns True/False for each element y, use **filter()**, example:

```
list(filter(lambda x: x < 'c' , y))
```

Or

```
my_iter = iter([True, False, True, False])
list(filter(lambda x: next(my_iter), y))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is rather simple to solve. Consider writing properly your list:

```
x = [True, False, True, False]
y = [a, b, c, d]  # assuming that a, b, c and d are some kind of object
output = []
for i, k in enumerate(x):
    if k:
        output.append(x[i])
```

Comment: Question was: *"I know how to do this using while/for loops, but I'm ideally looking for an elegant one-line of code"*